# Hello, I am new to dapp development, I am trying to start a geth node on android

Tags: dapp-development

but my application crashes after launching it, here is the error it tells me in my logcat [image]

In my MainActivity.java

> Blockquote

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   //private TextView accDisplayTextView;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       //accDisplayTextView = findViewById(R.id.acc_display_textview);

       try {
           NodeConfig nc = new NodeConfig();
           Node node = Geth.newNode(getFilesDir() + "/.ethNode", nc);
           node.start();

           GethNodeHolder gethNode = GethNodeHolder.getInstance();
           gethNode.setNode(node);

       } catch (Exception e) {
           Log.e("error: ", e.getMessage());
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
}
```

and my other error is that java cannot resolve the keystore class from org.ethereum.geth package

> Blockquote

```
import org.ethereum.geth.KeyStore;
```

Can you Help me please

Comment: Why u need to start it on android? Can’t you have an external node like infura or ganache and connect to it using Web3j !?

Comment: Yes it's a possibility, i have already experienced it for a web dapp, but I want to have my own node and be independent, I do not want to go through any third party and keep the peer to peer aspect and especially learn the solution of light client

Comment: Hi rim221 and welcome! Instead of screenshots of your code, we usually ask users to paste their code in formatted codeblocks (using three backtics: ```). You can edit your question using the "edit" button right under the tags. Could you do that?

Comment: Hi , changes have been made.